# react-native-modal not working with pressable in RN 0.73.6

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-modal

I have a new RN project (0.73.6).

I am adding a modal with the package react-native-modal.

Simplified code:

```
const TimeModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      isVisible={props.show}
      hasBackdrop={true}
      onBackdropPress={props.hide}
    >
        <Pressable onPress={props.hide}>
            <Text>Hide this modal</Text>
        </Pressable>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

The problem seems to be that `Pressable`-components are not working inside the modal. When I switch the Pressable in the modal with a `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, the modal is hiding. But the backdropPress-function is still not working.

Is this a known bug in RN 0.73.6? I can't find anything about it, I searched on both the github repos for RN and react-native-modal.

I wrapped the main component App in gestureHandlerRootHOC.

Comment: I don't think it's Pressable issue. You need to check if the props.hide is called when you click the Pressable component.